# How do I add a caret (down wards) using CSS next to link (anchor tag)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to add a caret symbol (down arrow or V) next to a menu item which has sub menu items. I know that it can be achieved using bootstrap. But, I can't update my custom css with bootstrap css as it would become messy.

I'm happy to integrate only a part of bootstrap if that is going to work.

Please suggest me a solution asap.

Comment: show us what have you tried using relevant code

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides, I'm not a css expert. I tried this.. .menu-parent a:after {  width: 0;  height: 0;  border-left: 20px solid transparent; border-right: 20px solid transparent; border-top: 20px solid #f00; }. It didn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try be using pure CSS to achieve a triangle:

Markup:

```
<div class="triangle"></div>
```

Style:

```
.triangle {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;

    border-top: 10px solid black;
}
```

As result, you have a solid down arrow that you can use. If you want to go beyond, you can override this property with another similar triangle over it and make an exactly caret in a "V" format:

Markup:

```
   <div class="triangle">
     <div class="over-triangle"></div>
   </div>
```

Style:

```
.triangle {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-top: 10px solid black;
}

.over-triangle {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-top: 5px solid white;
    position: relative;
    top: -10px;
    left: -5px;
}
```

This way you can get the exact form of a caret: [image]

You can apply it to another element by making the triangle `display: inline-table` to align to the same line.

Now, it goes to you implement it on links!

Comment: Thank you so much. Can you please send me the code for exact caret in a 'reverse V' format? Sorry to ask you. I'm not a CSS expert.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for easy symbol intergrations, I would suggest font-awesome if you want to avoid bootstrap.

http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/

Comment: But not if you just need a caret :)